# Model property bound to textbox always returns null

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model property bound to a textbox for a HTML form. However, whenever the form is submitted, the property is always null when it gets to the controller.

I have used the same technique countless times before but it just doesn't seem to want to play in this case.

This is the call from the controller:

```
    public ActionResult ScanTubsetLabelToClose()
    {
        CloseTubsetVM viewModel = new CloseTubsetVM();

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

This is the viewmodel:

```
public class CloseTubsetVM
{
    public string ToClose { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
@using PR3Transfer.Models.ViewModels;

@model CloseTubsetVM        

@using (Html.BeginForm("TubSetLabelToCloseScanned", "CloseTubset", new { closingBarcode = Model.ToClose, symbology = "KEY", }))
{            
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToClose, new { @class = "scanTextbox", onkeypress = "posKeyPress(event)" })

    <div>
        <input class='hiddenButton' type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div> 
}
```

And this is the target controller method:

```
    public ActionResult TubSetLabelToCloseScanned(string closingBarcode, string symbology)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

My only guess is that I'm getting away with something when I do the same thing elsewhere that isn't working here, but what?

Comment: Why are you not using a `CloseTubsetVM` object as parameter for the POST action?

Comment: We haven't been doing MVC3 that long and we tried to pass viewmodels between controller methods in the early days and it didn't work so we've just passed parameters or JSON since then. But you're perfectly right - it does work here. Incidentally, the problem with the code I posted is that the property name needs to match the parameter name. This must have been something I just did without thinking about it in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my earlier comment:

*The property name needs to match the parameter name.*

So, this is the corrected target controller method:

```
    public ActionResult TubSetLabelToCloseScanned(string barcode, string symbology)
    {
        //...
    }
```

And this is the corrected view:

```
@using PR3Transfer.Models.ViewModels;

@model CloseTubsetVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("TubSetLabelToCloseScanned", "CloseTubset", new { barcode = Model.Barcode, symbology = "KEY", }))
{            
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Barcode, new { @class = "scanTextbox", onkeypress = "posKeyPress(event)" })

    <div>
        <input class='hiddenButton' type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accept ToClose as a parameter and you will receive value for the model property

```
public ActionResult TubSetLabelToCloseScanned(string closingBarcode, string symbology, string ToClose)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult TubSetLabelToCloseScanned(string ToClose, string symbology)
    {
        // ...
    }
```